# How to get the result of dtwclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

now I'm using `dtwclust` package (Thanks to Author Alexis Sarda-Espinosa & Alexis Sarda~)

I'm stuck on an easy issue. Here is my code.

```
sc <- read.table("D:/handling data/confirm.csv", header=T, sep="," )
rownames(sc) <- sc$STDR_YM_CD
sc$STDR_YM_CD <- NULL
sc <- t(sc)
hc_sbd <- dtwclust(sc, type = 'h', k=3L, method = 'average', preproc = zscore,
               distance = 'dtw', control = list(trace=TRUE) )

plot(hc_sbd@cluster)
plot(hc_sbd, type='sc')
plot(hc_sbd, type='series', clus=2)
plot(hc_sbd, type='centroids', clus=2)

head(hc_sbd)
write.xlsx(hc_sbd, "D:/handling data/tab1clustn.xlsx")
```

I got this picture.
And I would like to export my data with cluster labels. like the second picture.

[image]
[image]

Here's my data link
http://blogattach.naver.com/e772fb415a6c6ddafd137d427d9ee7953f6e9146/20170207_141_blogfile/khm2963_1486442387926_THgZRt_csv/confirm.csv?type=attachment

Comment: can you share your data

Comment: Oh ok. haha sorry. I'm late

Comment: can you share the csv file? or `dput` your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume STDR_YM_CD is your unique identifier which you would like to cluster with DTW.

```
sc <- read.table("D:/handling data/confirm.csv", header=T, sep="," )
df.labels <- sc$STDR_YM_CD    #rownames(sc) <- sc$STDR_YM_CD
sc$STDR_YM_CD <- NULL
sc <- t(sc)

hc_sbd <- dtwclust(sc, type = 'h', k=3L, method = 'average', preproc = zscore,
           distance = 'dtw', control = list(trace=TRUE) )

hc.clust <- data.frame(STDR_YM_CD = df.labels, dtwclust = hc_sbd@cluster)

sc <- merge(sc,hc.clust, by.x = "STDR_YM_CD", by.y = "STDR_YM_CD")
```

I just extract the labels, the variable you are trying to cluster, then I create a new data frame from the dtwclust result with the column name dtwclust. I think merge them back based on our unique labels. There are other ways to do this as well, but this is one option. I hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks~ really great answer~~
Have a good day~~
You are great guy~~

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @Wayne Lee is over doing it. There is no need to declare a `data.frame` and we do not need to to `merge` the data.

All clustering algorithms I know, return a cluster assignment vector `cluster`, which has the same length as `df` has rows. Theforefore just `cbind` the `cluster` vector to your data `df`:

```
add_cluster_to_csv<-cbind(df,cluster=hc_sbd@cluster)
```

This should also reduce computation time, since we do not use `merge` and `cbind` is much faster than `data.frame`.

**Appendix:**

The whole code would look like this:

```
### Pass the data into a dataframe:
df <- read.csv('D:/handling data/confirm.csv',header=TRUE,sep=',')

### Run dtwclust:
hc_sbd <- dtwclust(sc, type = 'h', k=3L, method = 'average', preproc = zscore,
               distance = 'dtw', control = list(trace=TRUE)
cluster <- hc_sbd@cluster                   ### Extract the cluster
add_cluster_to_csv<-cbind(df,cluster)       ### Combine the original dataframe with the vector 

### Write to new csv:
write.csv(add_cluster_to_csv,'Csv_with_cluster.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you edit your answer to explain how your answer is different from the accepted one? I do not see that yet. Also read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Comment: In addtion your answer has servere formatting problems. All the text you put there is only a comment on the code. No interaction with the OP's question or the previous answer

Comment: mh no idea how I overlooked this. But is `dataf`=`df`?! If not how is `dataf` defined?

Comment: In addition do I understand your answer correctly? The `df`-data,frame has the same amount of rows as the cluster-vector has elements? Therefore the merge statement is actually redundant in the first answer, right?

Comment: Edited the dataf to df name. Assuming we cluster the data rowwise there shouldn't be a difference in the amount of rows with the cluster column the algorithm produced.  Therefore the merge becomes redundant like you mention.

Comment: I edited your answer one more time to give you a practical example what I meant with my first comment. The edit may take a bit of time to get approved. I hope this helps you in your future answers ;)